# Conditional expectation of poisson procces problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, expected-value, poisson-process

Let $N_{t}^{i}$  - be three independent Poisson processes of intensity $1$. $\tau$ = $\inf\{t: \,N_{t}^{3} = 1\}$, $X^{i}$ = $N_{\tau}^{i}$ (means that $X^{i}$ - the values of the first two processes at the moment the third level reaches $1$). Find the conditional expectation $E(X^{1}|X^{2})$.

Comment: Share your thoughts please.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot approach this task in any way. Perhaps you can give me the right thought. I thought that, since all $3$ Poisson processes are independent, then $E$($X^{1}$|$X^{2}$) = $EX^{1}$ ?

Comment: It's not clear that $X^1 = N_\tau^1$ and $X^2 = N_\tau^2$ are independent as you are evaluating both processes at the same random time $\tau$.

Comment: Why? $\tau$ is just stopping time, which depends only on $N^{3}$, while all $N^{i}$ are independent with each other.

Comment: For example, if you know that $N_\tau^2=1000$, then $\tau$ is likely to be large and so too is $N_\tau^1$. This is not rigorous of course but it shows why they could be dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since $N^3$ is a Poisson process with intensity $1$, $\tau$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$ and is independent of $N^1$ and $N^2$. Since $X^2$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X^1|X^2] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^1 \mathbf{1}_{X^2=n}]}{\mathbb{P}(X^2=n)} \mathbf{1}_{X^2 = n}.
$$
Start by computing $\mathbb{P}(X^2 = n)$:
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(N^2_\tau = n) &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(N^2_t = n|\tau = t)\mathbb{P}(\tau \in dt) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(N^2_t = n) e^{-t} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}e^{-2t}\, dt = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{align}$$
Here I used the independence of $N^2$ and $\tau$ in the second equality. Similarly,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N^1_\tau \mathbf{1}_{N^2_\tau = n}] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}[N_t^1 \mathbf{1}_{N_t^2 = n} | \tau = t] e^{-t} \, dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}[N_t^1]\mathbb{P}(N_t^2 = n) e^{-t} \, dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!} e^{-2t} \, dt = \frac{n+1}{2^{n+2}}.
\end{align}$$
Finally, we get that
$$\mathbb{E}[X^1|X^2] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{X^2 = n} = \frac{X^2+1}{2}.$$

Comment: Please explain the last equality. The fraction is multiplied by an indicator that has its own n in every term of the sum. Why did we get what we got?

Comment: The sum means: whenever $X^2 =n$ for some $n$, $\mathbb{E}[X^1|X^2] = \frac{n+1}{2}$. The conclusion should be clear from this

Comment: Oh, I understand, thank you!